# How to get the beginning address and ending address of a stack in C

Tags: c, stack

For some reason, I want to get the address ranges of a stack. For example, consider the following example:

```
int main(){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
}
```

Is there any generic way I can know the address of a and b (and another other variable on stack), without explicitly use `&a` in code?
Thanks!

Comment: The C specification doesn't mention a stack, or where local variables might be stored. So no there's no possible way to get the range of "a stack". And why do you want to know? What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you think getting the range of the stack might help? Also please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), as your question currently is one.

Comment: *"For some reason, I want to get the address ranges of a stack"* - Is that reason for anything *other* than writing a buffer overflow exploit?

Comment: If you want to know the address of `a`, then do `&a`. Why are you rejecting the solution to your problem?

Comment: It looks like you have a solution looking for a problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm in the same boat, i'm re-reading K&R, and i've decided to start playing around with sbrk even though it's obsolete, and now i'm wondering about the other sections in the program and how to find the boundaries. It would be super cute to have some software to print out everything in ram that belongs to the process, all the sections, their contents etc. This isn't something that makes sense or has a purpose, it's a curiousity thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory address in general, and stacks in particular, are system specific. There exists no way to obtain such information in standard C, nor is there a way to set the stack pointer in C.

In fact if you *don't* use the `&` operator, the variables are quite likely to get allocated in registers instead of the stack.

For the rare case where you actually need to know the stack address, for example when dealing with low level embedded systems, you'd typically go check a linker script and hardcode the value, or use some specific non-standard compiler extension.